# Indexing into array of functions: Expression resolves to an unused l-value

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to index into an array of functions but I get the error: "Expression resolves to an unused l-value".  I have tried to google what this means but information is scarce and what I find seems unrelated.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?  Any help would be much appreciated ! Thank you.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    var chart =  cell.contentView.viewWithTag(42) as TKChart
    chart.delegate = self
    chart.removeAllData(); //needed because of cell recycling

    var userDef1 = 1
    var userDef2 = 1

    func lineChart() -> TKChart {...}
    func columnChart() -> TKChart {...}

    var chartsArray = [AnyObject]()


    if userDef1 == 1{
        chartsArray.append(lineChart())
    }


    if userDef2 == 1{
        chartsArray.append(columnChart())
    }


     if indexPath.row == 0{
        chartsArray[0]  **error: Expression resolves to an unused l-value**
    }


    if indexPath.row == 1{
        chartsArray[1]   **error: Expression resolves to an unused l-value**
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: The chartsArray[i] is returning a value which is not being used. Swift thinks it is an error because the left hand side value of the only expression in the if conditional is not being used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`chartsArray[0]` is analagous to writing just the *result* of `lineChart()`; you're identifying a value, but not actually doing anything with it.

Comment: Ok, but if I write just lineChart() it evaluates, chart is drawn with no errors.  How can I attain the same result by using an array?

Comment: try chartsArray[0]()   You have to just save the function type in the array and return and invoke it, for it to work properly

Answer (score 1):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    var chart =  cell.contentView.viewWithTag(42) as TKChart
    chart.delegate = self
    chart.removeAllData(); //needed because of cell recycling

    var userDef1 = 1
    var userDef2 = 1

    func lineChart() -> TKChart {...}
    func columnChart() -> TKChart {...}

    var chartsArray = [AnyObject]()


    if userDef1 == 1{
        chartsArray.append(lineChart)
   }


    if userDef2 == 1{
        chartsArray.append(columnChart)
    }


     if indexPath.row == 0{
        chartsArray[0]()  
    }


    if indexPath.row == 1{
        chartsArray[1]()   
    }

     return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  Since both gave the same correct solution, I have to select the first responder as the "correct" answer. Thanks